# How to validate a public and private key pair in Java

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa

Is there a way to validate in java if the given private key, say certain *.key file matches with the certain public key, to a certain .pub file using RSA algorithm?

Comment: You did not specify the algorithm used, but maybe this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428236/given-two-ssh2-keys-how-do-i-check-that-they-belong-to-the-same-key-pair-in-java

Comment: Its RSA algorithm, specified in the tags and updated the question. And thanks for the link.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can verify if a key pair matches by

- creating a **challenge** (random byte sequence of sufficient length)
- **signing** the challenge with the **private key**
- **verifying** the signature using the **public key**

This gives you a sufficiently high confidence (almost certainity) that a key pair matches if the signature verification is ok, and an absolute certainity that a key pair does not match otherwise.

Example code:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyGen.initialize(2048);

KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();

// create a challenge
byte[] challenge = new byte[10000];
ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBytes(challenge);

// sign using the private key
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
sig.initSign(privateKey);
sig.update(challenge);
byte[] signature = sig.sign();

// verify signature using the public key
sig.initVerify(publicKey);
sig.update(challenge);

boolean keyPairMatches = sig.verify(signature);
```

This also works with **Elliptic Curve (EC)** key pairs, but you need to use a different signature algorithm (`SHA256withECDSA`):

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
keyGen.initialize(new ECGenParameterSpec("sect571k1"));
...
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! And I must research on this code too.

Comment: And can you provide any link related to this, so I can understand it's working?

Comment: Java tutorial: generating and verifying signatures -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/index.html

Comment: Usually signatures are used to verify that a message was not altered. It can also be used to identify the parties (one owning the private key, the other owning the public key) by using a challenge that is signed and then verified. We use this for authentication: server poses a challenge, client signs it (with the private key) and the server validates the identity by verifying the signed challenge (with the client's public key).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, will look into the link too.

Answer (score 9):

The answer that was marked as being correct wastes a lot of CPU cycles. This answer is waaaay more CPU efficient:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyGen.initialize(2048);

KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
RSAPrivateCrtKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateCrtKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();

// comment this out to verify the behavior when the keys are different
//keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
//publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();

boolean keyPairMatches = privateKey.getModulus().equals(publicKey.getModulus()) &&
    privateKey.getPublicExponent().equals(publicKey.getPublicExponent());
```

(the other answer signs a message with the private key and then verifies it with the public key whereas my answer checks to see if the modulus and public exponent are the same)

Comment: This answer does not work with general key pairs (EC, DSA, ...) but only with RSA key pairs.

Comment: @PeterWalser - that's true but the OP's question was "_using RSA algorithm_". But even then, you still don't need to sign / verify, even with EC or DSA. With EC you'd check to make sure that the curve is the same along with the QA parameter. Technically, I suppose a EC private key might not have QA available but I feel like most real world EC keys would just as most real world RSA private keys have the public exponent embedded within them. I mean, like with RSA, technically, all you need is the modulus and the private exponent but most real world RSA private keys include CRT components as well

Comment: In theory an RSA privatekey can be n,d only but in practice everyone uses the CRT-form of [PKCS1 A.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#appendix-A.1.2) which requires e. For X9-type EC [SEC1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5915#section-3) makes the public point OPTIONAL and I've seen plenty both ways -- but in Java the interface `ECPrivateKey` can't _access_ the public even if it is in the provider object. DSA, DH, EdDSA and XDH private keys standardly _don't_ contain the public, although some things (not Java) sometimes use rfc5958 to add it.

Answer (score 0):

`boolean keyPairMatches = privateKey.getModulus().equals(publicKey.getModulus()) && privateKey.getPublicExponent().equals(publicKey.getPublicExponent());`

`java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey` doesn't have getPublicExponent() method.

`org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.RSAPrivateKey` has getPublicExponent() method.

So,if you don't want to use `bouncycastle`, you have to use the `sign&verify` answer.

Comment: `interfaces.RSAPrivateKey` doesn't, but in practice more than 99.9999% of RSA private key objects in Java actually implement (and can be cast to) the _subinterface_ `interfaces.RSAPrivateCrtKey` which does, as neubert's code correctly shows.

Comment: And for that matter, Bouncy `asn1.pkcs.RSAPrivateKey` only works if you have a CRT-from encoding, and in that case you can write an ad-hoc DER parser good enough to get n and e in about 10 lines of code.