# How to check if generated keypair matches?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, jce

Is there a way I can check if a private-key matches a public-key with Java JCE?

```java
    // generate a keypair
    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance ("RSA", provname);
    kpg.initialize (4096);
    KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair ();

    // does kp.getPublic () matches kp.getPrivate ()???
```

Best I can think of is to use it.

```java
    // sign and verify
    Signature sign = Signature.getInstance ("SHA256withRSA", "BC");
    sign.initSign (kp.getPrivate ());
    String str ="text";
    sign.update (str.getBytes());
    byte sv [] = sign.sign ();  
    sign.initVerify(kp.getPublic());
    sign.update (str.getBytes ());
    boolean x=sign.verify (sv);       // must be true if keys match!
```

But maybe there is another easier way??

Comment: "matches" as in "this public key belongs to this private key"? When you have a `KeyPair` instance, why shouldn't they "match"?

Comment: I extend my sample and not use KeyPair but PrivateKey and PublicKey Instances. I just put it with a KeyPair to have keys to test with.

Comment: What assumptions can you make about the `PrivateKey` and `PublicKey` instances?

Comment: The private RSA key also contains the public RSA key (the public RSA key consists of modulus n and public exponent e). So you only need to compare whether n and e of the public RSA key correspond to the respective values of the private RSA key, see e.g. this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66021798/9014097.

Comment: @Topaco: The minimal RSA private, supported by the Java [RSAPrivateKey](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/interfaces/RSAPrivateKey.html) interface, need not contain the public exponent. [RSAPrivateCrtKey](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/interfaces/RSAPrivateCrtKey.html) does contain the public exponent.

Comment: The signature-verify method is probably "easiest" in terms of the least code if you want to support multiple public-key algorithms in their various flavors, e.g. RSA and ECDSA. It is, however, probabilistic, but the probability of a false positive is negligible for the common large parameter sizes in practical cryptography. Direct comparison of BigInteger components will be faster, but it's very specific to the particular asymmetric algorithm.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk - It is worth pointing out that not every interface allows access to `e` (e.g. `PrivateKey` or as you mentioned `RSAPrivateKey` do not). What I meant is that for RSA `kp.getPrivate()` and also `KeyFactory#generatePrivate(PKCS8EncodedKeySpec)` return an instance of `RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl()` *at runtime*, which also contains the public exponent `e`. In the linked answer to my last comment, the OP can find a code snippet that shows how access to `e` is possible (with `RSAPrivateCrtKey`).