# connect mac via ssh from pc

Tags: bash, macos, ssh

I'm trying to connect a mac machine from windows via git bash but always get permission denied
I'm using the git bash to windows to call via ssh the remote mac
I located the public key on the mac on the authorized_keys and open on the mac the remote connection 
here is my log :

```
>  OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016 debug1: Reading
> configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config debug2: resolving "10.10.10.73"
> port 22 debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0 debug1: Connecting to
> 10.10.10.73 [10.10.10.73] port 22. debug1: Connection established. debug1: identity file /c/Users/QTTEST/.ssh/id_rsa type 1 debug1:
> key_load_public: No such file or directory debug1: identity file
> /c/Users/QTTEST/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1 debug1: key_load_public: No
> such file or directory debug1: identity file
> /c/Users/QTTEST/.ssh/id_dsa type -1 debug1: key_load_public: No such
> file or directory debug1: identity file
> /c/Users/QTTEST/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1 debug1: key_load_public: No
> such file or directory debug1: identity file
> /c/Users/QTTEST/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1 debug1: key_load_public: No such
> file or directory debug1: identity file
> /c/Users/QTTEST/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1 debug1: key_load_public: No
> such file or directory debug1: identity file
> /c/Users/QTTEST/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1 debug1: key_load_public: No
> such file or directory debug1: identity file
> /c/Users/QTTEST/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1 debug1: Enabling
> compatibility mode for protocol 2.0 debug1: Local version string
> SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3 debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote
> software version OpenSSH_7.4 debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH*
> compat 0x04000000 debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK debug1:
> Authenticating to 10.10.10.73:22 as 'snakash' debug3:
> hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/QTTEST/.ssh/known_hosts"
> debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file
> /c/Users/QTTEST/.ssh/known_hosts:3 debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1
> keys from 10.10.10.73 debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs:
> ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa debug3:
> send packet: type 20 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent debug3: receive
> packet: type 20 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received debug2: local client
> KEXINIT proposal debug2: KEX algorithms:
> curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
> debug2: host key algorithms:
> ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
> debug2: ciphers ctos:
> chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
> debug2: ciphers stoc:
> chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
> debug2: MACs ctos:
> umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
> debug2: MACs stoc:
> umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
> debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib debug2:
> compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib debug2: languages ctos:
> debug2: languages stoc: debug2: first_kex_follows 0 debug2: reserved 0
> debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal debug2: KEX algorithms:
> curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
> debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256 debug2:
> ciphers ctos:
> aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour,aes128-cbc,aes256-cbc debug2:
> ciphers stoc:
> aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour,aes128-cbc,aes256-cbc debug2:
> MACs ctos:
> umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
> debug2: MACs stoc:
> umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
> debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com debug2: compression
> stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com debug2: languages ctos: debug2: languages
> stoc: debug2: first_kex_follows 0 debug2: reserved 0 debug1: kex:
> algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org debug1: kex: host key
> algorithm: rsa-sha2-512 debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr
> MAC: umac-64-etm@openssh.com compression: none debug1: kex:
> client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64-etm@openssh.com
> compression: none debug3: send packet: type 30 debug1: expecting
> SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY debug3: receive packet: type 31 debug1: Server
> host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:ajVznLdYmBlO8AZlvhT/4r3/U/DuGXbYLzn1SHDMtAA
> debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file
> "/c/Users/QTTEST/.ssh/known_hosts" debug3: record_hostkey: found key
> type RSA in file /c/Users/QTTEST/.ssh/known_hosts:3 debug3:
> load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.10.10.73 debug1: Host
> '10.10.10.73' is known and matches the RSA host key. debug1: Found key
> in /c/Users/QTTEST/.ssh/known_hosts:3 debug3: send packet: type 21
> debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1 debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
> debug3: receive packet: type 21 debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0 debug1:
> rekey after 4294967296 blocks debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
> debug2: key: /c/Users/QTTEST/.ssh/id_rsa (0x60006be30) debug2: key:
> /c/Users/QTTEST/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0) debug2: key:
> /c/Users/QTTEST/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0) debug2: key:
> /c/Users/QTTEST/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0) debug3: send packet: type 5
> debug3: receive packet: type 7 debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
> debug1: kex_input_ext_info:
> server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
> debug3: receive packet: type 6 debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received debug3: send packet: type 50
> debug3: receive packet: type 51 debug1: Authentications that can
> continue: publickey debug3: start over, passed a different list
> publickey debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
> debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey debug3: remaining preferred:
> keyboard-interactive,password debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
> debug1: Next authentication method: publickey debug1: Offering RSA
> public key: /c/Users/QTTEST/.ssh/id_rsa debug3: send_pubkey_test
> debug3: send packet: type 50 debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait
> for reply debug3: receive packet: type 51 debug1: Authentications that
> can continue: publickey debug1: Trying private key:
> /c/Users/QTTEST/.ssh/id_dsa debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: DSA
> SHA256:ER5BFLVzxl0i+fpp9OIRLEhlGUZig2vPv3DmCnm99Ls debug3: send
> packet: type 50 debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
> debug3: receive packet: type 51 debug1: Authentications that can
> continue: publickey debug1: Trying private key:
> /c/Users/QTTEST/.ssh/id_ecdsa debug3: no such identity:
> /c/Users/QTTEST/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory debug1:
> Trying private key: /c/Users/QTTEST/.ssh/id_ed25519 debug3: no such
> identity: /c/Users/QTTEST/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
> debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method debug1: No more
> authentication methods to try. Permission denied (publickey).
```

This issue happen to my only on this mac and i can not figure up what went wrong

Comment: What key is expected to work? Can you post the code somehow sane-formated? What errors you see in the server log?

Answer (score 1):

Check if .ssh directory and authorized_keys file on server have correct permissions. They should be readable only by owner (e.g. 700 mask for directory and 600 for file).

Make sure that correct identity is loaded in your ssh debug output.

Finally test if private key you using corresponds to public key on server (here are instructions how to do it: [How do you test a public/private DSA keypair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274560/how-do-you-test-a-public-private-dsa-keypair))

It is also worth to look into sshd log on server. On Mac it usually writes to /var/log/system.log